# Empty cell in Google Sheets not treated as empty by MATCH function

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to use the `=MATCH("zzzz";$A2:2)` function to find the column containing the last non-empty cell in row 2 of my [worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vladUkYHFwftcOOML8UduTJJQPFMqb1GQukOdLTMMow/edit?usp=sharing) (containing text values).

The value returned (4) implies that the cell `D2` is non-empty, even though it appears to be so, and the `EQ` function says its content is equal to that of the *truly empty* neighboring cell `C2`.

If I copy `C2` onto `D2`, or if I select `D2` and choose "delete value" from the menu, the problem is fixed. The correct behavior is displayed in rows 5 and 6.

Actually the problem originally occurs in a much larger worksheet, and I cannot afford to fix all "pseudo-empty" cells manually. One first step would be to figure out what is the hidden content of cell `D2`, which is considered empty by the `EQ` function but not by the MATCH function.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is missing the `search_type` parameter, which makes the `match()` function use its default and assume that the data is sorted. This means that it uses a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm), which will not work with unsorted data such as the data in the sample spreadsheet. This explains the unexpected result.

To make it work, add a `search_type` parameter of `0` and sort the data in reverse order by column number, or preferably apply this pattern:

```
=xmatch("?*"; arrayformula(to_text(A2:2)); 2; -1)
```

The formula must go to a row other than row `2`.

See [match()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) and [xmatch()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12406049).

Comment: I applied the XMATCH suggestion to my large spreadsheet and it works great. 
On the other hand, I am not sure that MATCH with the FALSE option would do the job since it would require an *exact* match, which will not necessarily be achieved.
And finally, I am still puzzled that the result can depend on the "content" of a nominally empty cell.
Anyway, thanks a lot for your help. I still have to understand properly _why_ your solution works ! Working on it…

Comment: `match()` supports wildcards. For example, to find the _first_ non-blank cell, you can use `=match("*", A2:2, 0)`. To search from the end, you can sort the data in reverse order by using `column()` as the sort key. To do the same with less steps, use `xmatch()`.

Comment: I did not know about XMATCH. It's very convenient. Thanks.